# Perform function but stop page from submitting

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am using the php code to empty my cart on my website if javascript is disabled. Only problem is that it empties the cart but submit the page too. I want it to remain on the same page and empty the cart because the page is supposed to submit for checking out not emptying the cart. Also I can't use javascript for this part because this is meant for user's who don't have javascript enabled.

I have tried using:

```
return false;
```

in the post function but it just made the page blank.

Here is my code:

```
<form method='post' action='checkout.php'>
    // some input
    <input type='submit'  id='cart-empty' name='cartEmpty' value='Empty' />
</form>

if($_POST['cartEmpty']) {
    $this->shippingfee = 0;
    $this->empty_cart();
}
```

Comment: If you don't have JavaScript available, then a full submit is your only option. You need to distinguish between "checkout" submits and "empty cart" submits, and handle them accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned in one of the comments that you weren't able to modify the headers (i.e. `header('Location: form.php);` because the header information has already been sent. To get around this, you should move your check for the posted `cartEmpty` value to the top of your submit page.

Headers are delivered any time content is echoed out to the browser (even white space such as blank lines), but if you do this processing prior to any output being sent, you have an opportunity to modify those headers still:

```
<?php
if($_POST['cartEmpty']) {
    $this->shippingfee = 0;
    $this->empty_cart();
    header("Location: cartEmptied.php");
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this php code for validation in checkout.php and return user to page(if user doesn't fill the form):

```
if(empty($_POST['cartEmpty'])){
    header("Location: ./form.php");
    die;
}
```

Comment: Tried that before too but I get Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at header.php:48)

Comment: You have only 2 solutions: 1) client side validation with javascript 2)server side validation with php

Comment: I had to move this code to the header to solve the problem... Thanks!